# If a line contains less than a certian amount of the same character

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
asd,asd,assdd,asdsdd,asd
asd,asd,asd,asd,asd
asd,asdasd,asd,asd
```

As you can see some lines only contain 3 commas. I would need those lines to be removed, preferably with notepad++ but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like replace regexp `^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\n` with `""`.

Not sure if NPP can replace newline in regexps easily.